# Dividing up Symfony2 Directory Structure by Client

Tags: symfony

In a multi-client scenario, where client entry points are sub-domains, I am wondering if I could separate my clients into directories that contain essentially the app ( like cache, config, logs, kernel) and then symlink back to a "core" Symfony directory for the rest (vendor, src, and web).   This lets me keep the application unified in regards to my bundles, but provides me with a separate config for each client. Then I point my sub-domains to their respective directories.

On the surface, it seems to be promising, and simpler than some other approaches I've been considering.
Later down the road if I want to upgrade a client to version 2 or add a component, I can switch bundles, or even point the symlinks to a whole new source. It might also scale well.
I am also wondering if using this approach would allow me to maintain separate security contexts between clients, as opposed to checking sub-domains and redirecting to authenticate if a user manually switched sub-domain.

Downsides would be duplication of several config files, and more involved initial client setup (but honestly nothing to bad in my opinion).

Is Symfony2 flexible enough to handle such a re-arrangement?
Are there benefits like speed or security separating the caches in multi client app?
Would using separate firewalls in each config result in separate security contexts for each sub-domain?

**Background/Additional information:**
I am re-developing an application to be multi client/tenant. I am using Symfony2 in the re-design since the original sat on top of Doctrine and I need more robust framework features now. I want to maintain a single application (its the same across all clients) and have individual databases for each client. My expectations are 100-200 clients max realistically (if I go over that, I'll celebrate and then worry about it).  The schema is the same between databases, I am separating for ease of backup/restore and for separate upgrade paths later.

I have spent time reading numerous questions and answers about multi-tenacy. Also about using routing and kernel listeners to use sub-domains to glean client ids and then dynamically selecting the Database Connections, etc..   I ended up finding a [blog post from Orm-designer.com outlining what they did when they moved their site to a new VPS](http://www.orm-designer.com/article/configuring-symfony-virtualhost-for-servergrove-vps). They detailed their directory structure in the post and it got me to thinking about how I might adapt the concept to suit my purposes.

Comment: Try to reduce the length, and focus on main information to do the questions... to avoid people that could help you doesn't read it because is too long.

Comment: @gsc-leticia There is nothing inherently wrong with long questions. In fact this one is particularly well written and well thought out making it easy to read. However, it is a bad fit for SO as it is asking for opinion and is not a specific coding problem as required by the [FAQ].

Comment: @gsc-leticia  - Moved question up and extra info to bottom section

Comment: @vascowhite - Asked some more precise questions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have:

- your application based on Symfony 2,
- database structure,
- several machines,

You need to:

- deploy your app on ~200 nodes (they could be located on different
  machines),
- keep the configuration easy to maintain,
- use the same source code for each application,

You need to:

- implement maintenance mode in your application,
- decide which files are user specyfic,
- all files that are not user specyfic sym-link to client folder from some shared place,
- implement rsync script to update the files that are common for all users,

Each time you want to update version of your application:

- let client know that your application will not be available for some
  time,
- put all applications into maintenance mode,
- rsync the common code among all machines and clear cache/deploy assets for each client,
- if needed prepare backup and run database update scripts,
- run functional tests on all client machine and switch off maintanence mode,

Client Folder:

```
Machine 1
  SourceFolder
    app
    bin
    src
      Company
        YourBundle
           *Controller
           Resources
             config
             *css
             ...
           ...
    *vendor
    web
```

Directories with * are sym-links to to folder shared by several clients on the same machine and rest of the directories are user specyfic.